# Chain rule applied on matrix calculus

Tags: calculus, matrices, derivatives

Given $\frac{\partial CE}{\partial Z}=\hat{y}-y$ and $Z=U^Tv_c$, where $\hat{y}, y, v_c$ are vectors and $U$ is a matrix. Find derivative  $\frac{\partial CE}{\partial v_c}$.

My solution:
$$\frac{\partial CE}{\partial v_c}=\frac{\partial CE}{\partial Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial v_c}=(\hat{y}-y)U$$

Given solution:
$$\frac{\partial CE}{\partial v_c}=U^T(\hat{y}-y)$$

I understand in my solution the dimension doesn't match. But according to chain rule, aren't we suppose to take the derivative calculation in some order like what I've done?

**Update:**

It might be helpful to mention that $CE \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the original gradient into a differential, then do a change of variable, and convert that into a gradient in terms of the new variable
$$\eqalign{
 d(C\!E) &= (\hat{y}-y):dz \cr
 &= (\hat{y}-y):U^Tdv_c \cr
 &= U(\hat{y}-y):dv_c \cr\cr
\frac{\partial\,C\!E}{\partial v_c} &= U(\hat{y}-y) \cr\cr
}$$
So it appears that neither solution is correct.